# Android - JSON - How do I create a JSON Object & JSON Array to match this format using JSONObject & JSONArray Types?

Tags: java, android, json

How do I create a JSON Object & JSON Array to match this format using JSONObject & JSONArray Types?

```
{"PeripheralList":
  [{"Category":"BP","CollectionTime":"2015-12-28T09:09:22-05:00",
    "DeviceInfo":null,
    "Readings":[
            [{"Name":"SYS","Type":"INT","Value":"200"},
            {"Name":"DIA","Type":"INT","Value":"199"},
            {"Name":"HTR","Type":"INT","Value":"102"},
            {"Name":"READINGTIME","Type":"DATETIME","Value":"2015-12-27T08:12:53-05:00"}]
        ]},

{"Category":"HR","CollectionTime":"2015-12-28T09:09:22-05:00",
    "DeviceInfo":[{"Name":"UNITS","Value":"Rate"}],
    "Readings":[
            [{"Name":"HR","Type":"DECIMAL","Value":"200.7"},
            {"Name":"READINGTIME","Type":"DATETIME","Value":"2015-12-27T07:26:49-05:00"}],

            [{"Name":"HR","Type":"DECIMAL","Value":"155.2"},
            {"Name":"READINGTIME","Type":"DATETIME","Value":"2015-12-27T14:39:11-05:00"}]
        ]}
]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the JSON string directly to the constructor.

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Below should give you an idea of how it works when you want to manually create a JSON Object.

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(); // Main Object.    
JSONArray categoryArray; // Category Array.    
JSONObject categoryObject; // Category Object.
JSONArray readingsMainArray; // An array of arrays.
JSONArray readingsChildArray; // A child array.
JSONObject readingsObject; // A readings entry.

// Create arrays.
readingsMainArray = new JSONArray();
readingsChildArray = new JSONArray();

// Create JSONObject.
readingsObject = new JSONObject();

// Put values.
readingsObject.put("Name":"SYS");
readingsObject.put("Type":"INT");
readingsObject.put("Value":"200");

// Add to the child array.
readingsChildArray.put(readingsObject);

// Repeat 3 times for the other values.

// Now add the readings child array to the main array.
readingsMainArray.put(readingsChildArray);

// Now the category JSONObject.
categoryObject = new JSONObject();

// Put values.
categoryObject.put("Category","BP);
categoryObject.put("CollectionTime","2015-12-28T09:09:22-05:00");
categoryObject.put("DeviceInfo",null);
categoryObject.put("Readings", readingsMainArray);

// Put the category object into the category array.
categoryArray = new JSONArray();
categoryArray.put(categoryObject);

// Repeat this process for the "second" category array.

// Add category array to the main object.
mainObject.put("PeripheralList",categoryArray);
```

Let me know if this helps.